# Mostrar fecha desde una consulta mysql en un input type date

Tags: php, html, mysql

en mi codigo html, tengo un formulario para editar  valores desde una consulta mysql.todos los campos se visualizan correctamente,excepto el campo "fecha". En dicho formulario utilizo un   `<input type="date" name="fecha_nac" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $row['fecha_nac'];?>>`
pero este solo muestra el datapicker de html5 con el placeholder dd/mm/aaaa.
¿como podria mostrar el valor contenido en la base de datos de ese campo tipo date?
el valor del campo "fecha" en la base de datos, tiene el formato "Y-m-d"

Answer (score 0):

Los input de tipo date esperan la fecha en formato YYYY-mm-dd, puedes comprobarlo en la documentación de https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Por lo tanto a tu valor de: $row['fecha_nac'] deberías añadirle un format y transformar la fecha a formato YYYY-mm-dd para que el input tipo date te lo reconozca.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. ¿conoces como seria la sintaxis correcta para añadirle ese formato (YYY-mm-dd) a la variable $row['fecha_nac'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso puedes hacer una función para no complicarte la existencia, lo cargas a un archivo funciones.php y le haces el llamado cada vez que lo requieras, también lo podrías hacer directamente con código php ya que la sintaxis es bastante sencilla.

```
$var=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var));
```

**functions.php**

```php
<?php
 function converToLatinDate($var) {
    if ($var == "") $var = "0000-00-00"; else {
    $var = date("Ymd", strtotime($var));
    }  
  return($var); 
 }
 
  function converToLatinDateString($var) {
    if ($var == "") $var = ""; else {    
    $var = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($var));
    }  
  return($var); 
 }

   function converToEnglishDate($var) {
    if ($var == "") $var = ""; else {    
    $var = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var));
    }  
  return($var); 
 }
?>
```

**index.php**

```php
<?php 
require ("functions.php");

$fecha = '2023-06-16';

$fecha = converToLatinDate($fecha);
echo "<br>".$fecha;
$fecha = converToLatinDateString($fecha);
echo "<br>".$fecha;
$fecha = converToEnglishDate($fecha);
echo "<br>".$fecha;
?>
```